# Can Xcode 4.6.x and Xcode 5 share project directories?

Tags: ios, xcode

After installing Xcode 5 I immediately noticed it bringing up the windows/projects from a previous Xcode 4.6 session. Of course this is expected behavior if I am upgrading, but since this is only a preview/beta release it made me a bit nervous....

Is it reasonably safe to let Xcode 5 and Xcode 4.6.2 point to the same project directories (maybe not while running simultaneously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is perfectly fine and I have been using mainly XCode5 but switching to 4.x every once in a while. The only thing to be careful of is when opening some files, it may ask if you want to convert them to XCode 5 format. If you do, you will not be able to open that file in XCode 4.X anymore (or so the warning says, I've never clicked yes).

Answer (score 0):

JSdodgers's answer is perfectly valid.

Upgrading XIBs is a big pain.
Note that you won't be able to use every new XIB feature in Xcode 5 if you don't use the Xcode 5 format.

The best solution is to have a separate branch (git or svn) for your iOS 7 code.